# Group Secure Information Sharing [GSAKMP]

Tags: security, network-security

I am working on a project based on group secure information sharing environment. We are developing a web application implementing GSAKMP (Group Secure Association Key Managment  protocol). Here is the link to its source code. 
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4535.txt
http://gsakmp.sourceforge.net/
Unfortunately the source code on this link is unavailable. Also related to the web based implementation there is no online help available. I am facing issues on HTTP Based group communication and group join request. Is there any one who can help in this regard. Its a generic call for help But I will discuss this in detail with the concerned person. Need a direction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try asking *specific* questions about things, and not only questions that can vary within a large spectrum. That way, people will be more likely to help out. :)

Comment: You are right the question is generic. But I wanted to filter out the people who have knowledge and experience of GSAKMP implementation, then I would discuss it in detail. If you have worked on GSAKMP please let me know I will post the specific question.